# Apache Pig - ERROR 2118: For input string: "4f8:0:a111::add:9898"

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

We recently upgraded the cluster to use Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.

After the change, we needed to reinstall pig, which used to work absolutely fine. After the installation [as described here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_16_2.html), the simplest HBase job does not get created.

> raw_protobuffer = LOAD 'hbase://data_table' USING
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('external_data:downloaded',
>   '-limit=1
>   -gte=0 -lte=1')
>   AS (data:bytearray);

Which fails with the magical:

> Failed Jobs: JobId    Alias   Feature Message Outputs
>   N/A   raw_protobuffer MAP_ONLY    Message:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: For
>   input string: "4f8:0:a111::add:9898"  at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1063)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1080)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:992)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:945)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:945)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:566)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:319)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:270)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:160)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)    at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:257)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "4f8:0:a111::add:9898"    at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.(DnsClient.java:122)     at
>   com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.(Resolver.java:61)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.getResolver(DnsContext.java:570)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:430)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:139)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLDirContext.getAttributes(GenericURLDirContext.java:103)
>     at
>   javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:142)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:85)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.reverseDNS(TableInputFormatBase.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTableInputFormat.getSplits(HBaseTableInputFormat.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
>     ... 16 more

We suspected permissions to tmp folder but they seem to be fine (i.e. the job directory gets created with the pig runner (!) being its owner). Any suggestion what we might have missed would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an IPv6 address to me - suggest you investigate disabling IPv6 functionality on your cluster

Comment: Thank you very much, @ChrisWhite, that was the right hint. If you could add this as an answer, I would be able to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an IPv6 address to me - suggest you investigate disabling IPv6 functionality on your cluster

Comment: The steps to disable it on Ubuntu can be found, for example here: http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntulinux-mint/. Also, in my case I needed to remove IPv6 entries in /etc/resolv.conf.